# PL/SQL Oracle Select tables in database by specific date range

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like to find out the table names which contains value falls in to specific date range in oracle SQL developer.

To be exact, tables in the database have the same columns called `MODIFY_DATE`.
First, I have to find out the latest `MODIFY_DATE` of each table among all records and see if that `MODIFY_DATE` is within 60 days from today.

If it does, than I have to include it to generate result with 2 columns: `Table_name` and `MODIFY_DATE`.

[My expected outcome is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwlTo.png).

Is anyone know the PL/SQL statement to do so?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You may need to make use of system tables and dynamic SQL to achieve the results I guess

Comment: @Avi Would you mind to explain more? The most difficult thing I encounter is that Table name is not the same layer to the table record in a query. Thank you

Comment: Are you saying that database table PPL_ID has a column named MODIFY_DATE ?

Comment: @Abra Yes, all tables in the database has a column named MODIFY_DATE

Comment: If any of the records in the table has a MODIFY_DATE is 60 days from now, print the Table_name and latest MODIFY_DATE

Comment: Avi's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61004449/pl-sql-oracle-select-tables-in-database-by-specific-date-range#comment107927055_61004449) is the answer. Use [dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011) to query each table and get the table names from Oracle's [data dictionary](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/datadict.htm#CNCPT002)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use the dynamic query in PL/SQL block. It can be achieved using the  `XMLQUERY` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
(select table_name, DATE'1900-01-01' + 
  TO_NUMBER(xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
    passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
      'select max(' || column_name || ' - DATE''1900-01-01'') as c '
      || 'from "' || table_name || '" WHERE MODIFY_DATE >= trunc(SYSDATE) - 60')) -- name of the column here
  returning content)) as modify_date
from user_tab_columns
where column_name = 'MODIFY_DATE') -- name of the column here
WHERE modify_date IS NOT NULL;
```

I have tested the code in my local DB using `START_DATE` as a column name and 1000 days as the restriction to show the example.

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM
  2  (select table_name, DATE'1900-01-01' +
  3    TO_NUMBER(xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
  4      passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
  5        'select max(' || column_name || ' - DATE''1900-01-01'') as c '
  6        || 'from "' || table_name || '" WHERE START_DATE >= trunc(SYSDATE) - 1000'))
  7    returning content)) as modify_date
  8  from user_tab_columns
  9  where column_name = 'START_DATE')
 10  WHERE modify_date IS NOT NULL;

TABLE_NAME      MODIFY_DA
--------------- ---------
ACTIVE_USERS    21-NOV-19
YOUR_TABLE      03-JAN-20

SQL>
```

Comment: Nice, this is great. I didn't know about this xml thing in oracle.

Comment: Thank you Tejash! I tried your code, it works but there is no expected outcome. I guess it's because those tables are not owned by me but I can access them. I tried to change user_tab_columns to all_tab_columns and this shows error message. Do you know why?

Comment: Ok, Then you need to use `all_tab_columns` table and also `|| 'from "' || table_name || '" WHERE` should be replaced with `|| 'from "' || owner || '"."' || table_name || '" WHERE`

Comment: It looks perfect but I still can't get the expected outcome, I even tried to include OWNER='HR' to make sure it works but the following message shown:ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: Can you please share the exact query that you are executing?

Comment: 1. SELECT * FROM
(select table_name, DATE'1900-01-01' + 
  TO_NUMBER(xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
    passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
      'select max(' || column_name || ' - DATE''1900-01-01'') as c '
      || 'from "' || owner || '"."' || table_name || '" WHERE MODIFY_DATE >= trunc(SYSDATE) - 60')) -- name of the column here
  returning content)) as modify_date
from all_tab_columns
where column_name = 'MODIFY_DATE') -- name of the column here
WHERE modify_date IS NOT NULL;

Comment: SELECT * FROM
(select table_name, DATE'1900-01-01' + 
  TO_NUMBER(xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
    passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
      'select max(' || column_name || ' - DATE''1900-01-01'') as c '
      || 'from "' || owner || '"."' || table_name || '" WHERE MODIFY_DATE >= trunc(SYSDATE) - 60')) -- name of the column here
  returning content)) as modify_date
from all_tab_columns
where owner = ‘HR’ and column_name = 'MODIFY_DATE') -- name of the column here
WHERE modify_date IS NOT NULL;

Comment: SELECT * FROM
(select table_name, DATE'1900-01-01' + 
  TO_NUMBER(xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
    passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
      'select max(' || column_name || ' - DATE''1900-01-01'') as c '
      || 'from "' || owner || '"."' || table_name || '" WHERE MODIFY_DATE >= trunc(SYSDATE) - 60')) -- name of the column here
  returning content)) as modify_date
from all_tab_columns
where column_name = 'MODIFY_DATE') -- name of the column here
WHERE owner = ‘HR’ and  modify_date IS NOT NULL;

Comment: @Tejash The first one is just replaced the code as you mentioned, the second and third is just adding OWNER='HR' into different places, three of them did processing but showing error message eventually. Thank you.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM
    ( SELECT
            TABLE_NAME,
            DATE '1900-01-01' + TO_NUMBER(XMLQUERY
            ('/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()' PASSING XMLTYPE
            (DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('select max('
                 || COLUMN_NAME || ' - DATE''1900-01-01'') as c ' || 'from "'
                 || OWNER || '"."' || TABLE_NAME || '" WHERE MODIFY_DATE >= trunc(SYSDATE) - 60'
                 ))  RETURNING CONTENT)) AS MODIFY_DATE
        FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
        WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'MODIFY_DATE'
            AND OWNER = 'HR' ) 
WHERE MODIFY_DATE IS NOT NULL;` works for me

Comment: I guess there maybe some hidden problem I don't know, thanks for helping anyway!